# How to generate a random ID for a user and save it in a file. This ID should be always accessable in Discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I came up with the idea of creating a unique ID system for my server with a ticket system. This is how it works:
When a user joins the server, the bot automaticlly generates and ID and it stores this ID in a file with the user ID from discord. If the user creates a ticket with the Bot, the bot adds the ID that it generated for the user into a message. Also, there should be a command, that allowes me to call the user and his ID.

This is the code, I wrote to generate the random ID

`random = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for n in range(8)])`

Now I want to access it in the ticket command like this:

```
@client.command(name='ticket-new')
async def create_channel(ctx, channel_name='unnamed_channel', *, reason=None):
    member = ctx.author
    guild = ctx.guild
    existing_channel = discord.utils.get(guild.channels, name=channel_name)
    
    reason_length = len(reason)
    missing_length = 50 - reason_length
    
    if reason_length < 50:
        await ctx.send(f'Hey, your ticket should be at least 50 characters long to relay it to the moderators. {missing_length} missing characters.')
        return   
            
    else:
        if existing_channel:
            await ctx.send(f'There is already a ticket with the name {channel_name}. Please selcet another name.')
        if not existing_channel:
            channel = await guild.create_text_channel(channel_name)

            await channel.set_permissions(guild.default_role, read_messages=False)
            await channel.set_permissions(ctx.author, read_messages=True)
            embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Ticket: {channel_name}", description=f"**Description**: {reason}\n**ID**: {random}")
            await channel.send(embed=embed)
            await member.send("Ticket: `" + channel_name + '` erstellt!')
            
            print(f'Creating a new ticket channel: {channel_name}, by {member.name}, at {ctx.message.created_at}, on: {guild.name}, ID: {random}')
```

Well ... my plan now is it to store *random* for user in a file. Also ... maybe how to access the information via command.

Comment: I dont see the point in creating your own id to associate to a user? This could mean duplicates occur, also every single thing in dpy is already a snowflake. I.e, every id is different afaik. Also just open the file you saved it to and read it? Shouldnt be hard

Comment: Well yeah true, and I'm just going to work with the user ID *laught*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it with SQL

For the code to work, you need:
1.Download SQLite Studio - https://sqlitestudio.pl/
2.Create new database file in SQLite Studio at the same directory that you have your discord bot code

Code:

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect('database_file_name.db')
cursor = db.cursor()

async def addUserID(user):
    serverID = user.guild.id
    id = 0

    # if user already have id in database the code will break
    try:
        if cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `{0}` WHERE `discord_id` = '{1}'".format(serverID, user.id)): return
    except: pass

    try:
        # if table for this server was already created
        for i in cursor.execute('SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `{}`'.format(str(serverID))): id = i[0]
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `{0}` (`user`, `discord_id`, `id`) VALUES('{1}', '{2}', '{3}')".format(serverID, user, str(user.id), id))
    except:
        # otherwise, it creates a table for this server and puts the user data there
        cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE `{}` ( `user` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL , `discord_id` INT NOT NULL , `id` INT NOT NULL )'.format(serverID))
        for i in cursor.execute('SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `{}`'.format(serverID)): id = i[0]
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `{0}` (`user`, `discord_id`, `id`) VALUES('{1}', '{2}', '{3}')".format(serverID, user, str(user.id), id))

# this function returns the id you wanted to implement, but before using this function you must use the addUserID() function
async def getUserID(user):
    try:
        for row in cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `{0}` WHERE `discord_id` = '{1}'".format(user.guild.id, user.id)): return row[2]
    except Exception as error:
        raise Exception('The user has no identifier. To add an ID to a user, use the addUserID(discord.Member) function\n\nError:\n' + str(error))


# when member joined it is adding to this member id and prints it
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
        await addUserID(member)
        print('Own user id: ' + await getUserID(member))
```

*Sorry for my english*